# Larvavel :login using custom middleware

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Recently I have started with laravel framework and i am implementing login functionality in an old fashioned way

```
Route::post('login',['as'=>'validatelogin','uses'=>'HomeController@login']);
Route::get('home/{page?}/{id?}','HomeController@home');
```

and in HomeController

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $matches=['email'=>$request->email];
        $users =User::where($matches)->first();
        if($users == FALSE)
        {
            $request->session()->flash(
            'errors',
            'Invalid Email');
           return redirect('/');    
        }
        else if($users->account_status==0)
        {
            $request->session()->flash(
            'errors',
            'Account is blocked please contact admin');
           return redirect('/');
        }
        else if (!Hash::check($request->password,$users->user_password))
        {
                $request->session()->flash('errors', 'Invalid Password');
                return redirect('/');    
        }
        else
        {
              //login success set the session values
              $request->session()->put('user',$users);
              //redirect to home
              return redirect('home');

        }
    }
```

in `home` function check whether the user session is exists if not redirect to login page, otherwise load the views based on user role.

```
public function home(Request $request,$page='admin-home',$id=null)
    {
        if(!$request->session()->has('user'))
        {
            $request->session()->flash('errors', 'Session is expired');
            return redirect('/');
        }
       //load the views based on roles

  }
```

How can i rewrite the above code using middlewares, i've found so many examples ,but can't get a proper solution

Comment: Look at the code in the auth middleware since Laravel already has this functionality, that would be a good place to review.

Comment: i've already noted that,but can't get it

Comment: Maybe you should rewrite your question with what you've tried and what isn't working then to make this more specific.

Comment: use laravel attemp() to login

Answer (score 1):

First I strongly recommend you to use the Laravel login. Currently when you put a user in the session you're not logging him in. Laravel uses the **Auth** facade to manage the user login, logout, guards, etc.

You can use `Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])` to automatically check for correct credentials and login (this method will return true on success). And after that you can use `Auth::check()` to see if a user is logged or the **auth** midleware to protect routes and contorllers, so you wont have to check if the user is logged inside them.